# syntax error near behavioral

Tags: vhdl, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to write a code for multiplying two 100x100 matrices in vhdl

```
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    library work;
    use work.mult_100x100_pack.all;


    entity multiplier_main_code is
        Port ( in_matrix1 : in  t_2d_array;
               in_matrix2 : in  t_2d_array;
               out_matrix : inout  t_2d_array);
    end multiplier_main_code;

    architecture Behavioral of multiplier_main_code is

    begin

        process(in_matrix1, in_matrix2)
        begin
             for i in 0 to 99 loop
                  for j in 0 to 99 loop
                      for k in 0 to 99 loop
                       out_matrix(i)(j) <= std_logic_vector(signed(out_matrix(i)(j)) + (signed(in_matrix1(i)(k)) * signed(in_matrix2(k)(j))));

                      end loop;
                 end loop;
          end loop;          

    end Behavioral;
```

**Its again and again showing an error saying:
          expecting type void for "behavioral"

          syntax error near "Behavioral"**

The code for mult_100X100_pack package is:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package mult_100x100_pack is

    type t_1d_array is array(integer range 0 to 99)of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    type t_2d_array is array(integer range 0 to 99)of t_1d_array;


end mult_100x100_pack;
```

**Please, can anybody help me to get around this error?**

Comment: this is just a typo... see answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing your indentation, it should be quite obvious what you are missing:

```
process(in_matrix1, in_matrix2)
begin
  for i in 0 to 99 loop
    for j in 0 to 99 loop
      for k in 0 to 99 loop
        -- Do things
      end loop;
    end loop;
  end loop;
-- Perhaps `end process;` might be appropriate here...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `process` needs an `end process;` :

```
     end loop;   

  end process;          

end Behavioral;
```

This illustrates the advantage of taking care to indent code correctly. If all your `end for`s lined up with their corresponding `for`s, this would have been obvious.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked. I want to accelerate the implementation of this algorithm. I've read a lot of research papers and different techniques but I don't know how to implement them....can you refer me to some material which can help me with this..that would be a great help!!